# What is the drawback of MSR Accelerator

Tags: c#, accelerator

Just tried it out and found it to be very simple and fast.

When i then tried to search the web for information about it I hardly found anything.

Why is that? Is there some huge drawback I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably missing real life problems that can be solved with this.  [Embarrassingly parallel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel) problems are uncommon.

Comment: Does ATI Stream and CUDA also have that drawback to the same extent?

Comment: It is not a hardware problem.